# weblogic11g setup

Tags: weblogic11g

anyone knows the steps to follow when installing and setting and creating domain in weblogic11g?

I have to deploy grails application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a config wizard that comes with the installation.  It is a GUI or a text based program that is easy to use.  Look for config.exe or config.sh in wlserver/common/bin